# Incorrect handling of metrics by the delta() function in Grafana

Tags: function, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I am using **prometheus-cpp library**, **Prometheus** and **Grafana** .
And I want to calculate the intensity of my application.
 This application processes files. 
I count the processing time of each file and send it to Prometheus as a counter.Increment(Processed_time). 
Then in Grafana I use the delta() function to calculate the intensity. 
The idea is this: if files were processed for 40 seconds in 1 minute, then the intensity is 40/60.
I am using the delta() function

```
delta(application_time_total_sec{}[1m]) / (60*1)
```

But there are two problems:

1. sometimes incorrect values ​​are obtained after the delta() function: they are greater than 1. It was as if my application worked 75 seconds in 1 minute))
   [incorrect values - they are greater than 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaZvn.jpg)
2. If I want to increase the interval from 1 minute to 5 minutes, then I get crazy data.

```
delta(application_time_total_sec{}[5m]) / (60*5)
```

Am I using the delta() function incorrectly?

Comment: A few comments: `delta()` is intended for gauges, I expect you total time to be a counter. In that case, `increase()`is the function to use;  if your application is multithreaded, the total time may be multiplied by the number of cpu used - it that the case ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez, I use a Counter and when I try increase() function, I get the same as delta() function.